# custom web accessibility error message when pressed enter with keyboard on submit button and input field is blank

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I am new to WAI-ARIA. The problem I am facing is, if chat Subject(Textarea) is left blank, it should read error message but Jaws doesn't read. And also when user hits enter with keyboard or mouse in same subject being blank scenario, it should read another message saying subject is required for initiating a chat.

I tried below code

```
function (e) {
      if ((e.keyCode==13 || e.key==13) && input[0].value =='') {


 var newAlert = document.querySelector("#MyerrorMSg");
        newAlert.setAttribute("role", "alert");
        newAlert.setAttribute("id", "alert");
    var msg="Please enter chat subject to start session";
        var content = document.createTextNode(msg);
        newAlert.appendChild(content);
        document.body.appendChild(newAlert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered aria-live regions?

Have an empty aria-live region in your DOM. Update it with content using JS each time you need to announce something
`document.querySelector('#validation-errors').innerHTML(error)`

```
<div role="region" id="validation-errors" aria-live="polite"></div>
```

Resources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your change , however multiple is not working . It reads only first region.

Comment: The idea is that you have a single region and you update its contents with anything you need to announce each time. That way is ensured that the screen reader won't announce multiple texts at the same time. It is the correct way to approach this since user won't be able to understand 2+ voices talking after all that's why multiple regions are not supported.